# linking to another part of the same page

Tags: html

I've been looking around online for a solution but the methods I've found don't work. The methods online tell me to do this

Make a div with a class and ID
I make one like this

```
<div class="paragraphBackground" id="paragraphBackground">
<p class="paragraphContent">content of    paragraph</p></div>
```

then it says to make a link like o have below.

```
<a href="#paragraphBackground" name="paragraphBackground">Goto paragraph</a>
```

But when I click on the goto paragraph it doesn't do anything.

What I'm wanting to use this for is a html readme for a mod that contains a sidebar on the left that shows all the contents of the readme and when you click on one of the links it will jump you to that section in that same HTML file.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle to show what you have tried already?

Comment: I put it in the post but It's not working lemme try something else. I will put it on a Google doc and link it. Give me a couple minutes

Comment: no, just put the link to jsfiddle.net into the comments

Comment: I'm using the android stack overflow client and the actual webpage is on my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following for the link: `<a href="#readme">`.

For the part that you want to scroll to, use this: `<div id="readme">Read me!</div>`

### [JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/q6me1gnd/).

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/huntmg90/

Basically you set a `<a name="identityofanchor" />` in front of your text you want linked, then to link to it you do a `<a href="#identityofanchor">label of anchor</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Your link will need to look something like this:

```
<a href="#paragraph1">Paragraph 1</a>
```

And the corresponding content needs to have:

```
<a name="paragraph1">Paragraph 1</a>
```

Here's a Fiddle to help: http://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/9mx5yx7d/

Comment: I will try some of these solutions when I get home and if they work I will check the correct one here